# Open webpage from a Java application doesn't work when run from task scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a Java program some time ago that automatically opens a webpage before I get to work in the morning. I do this by calling a batch file from Java, which opens the webpage. This program worked great for about three or four months without any problems, but one day it just stopped working. I have tried opening the webpage from within Java as well instead of the batch file, but I consistently run into a problem. This is the process I use:

- I exported my program as a runnable JAR and converted it to an EXE using Launch4j. In my Windows task scheduler I schedule it to run at 5:30am every morning.
- My Java program calls the batch file that is stored on my desktop
- The batch file opens Chrome and calls the webpage to open

When I run the Java program EXE manually (double-click from the desktop) it runs correctly, calls the batch file, and opens the webpage. However, when I try running the EXE from the Windows task scheduler it does not (visibly) open the webpage. It does appear to run Chrome in the background (according to the task manager/Process Explorer) but the webpage itself doesn't seem to open (I can tell because the webpage I open should be playing music, but I hear nothing).

This is the Java function I use to run the batch file:

```
public static void openWebpage() throws Exception {
    String[] startupBat = {"cmd", "/c", "start", "/B", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\WebpageStart.bat"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(startupBat);
    try {
        webpage = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logWriter.write(tf.format(new Date()).toString() + " - Unable to start webpage");
    }
    if (webpage != null) {
        try {
            webpage.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logWriter.write(tf.format(new Date()).toString() + " - Webpage startup interrupted");
        } finally {
            webpage.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the contents of the batch file I use to start the webpage:

```
@echo off

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.myWebpage.com
```

Once again, everything works fine when I run the Java EXE manually, but when I try to run it from the task scheduler the webpage doesn't appear to open. What could cause this sort of behavior? What changes when the task scheduler runs a program vs. when it is manually run?

Comment: I'm guessing the scheduled task is running as a different user with restricted permissions. I'd check your windows error log for errors

Comment: I'm looking under "Windows Logs" and I see a large number of "Audit Failure" entries under "Security". I have no idea what these are. Could these be pointing to the problem? I have checked the box under "General" in the task scheduler saying "Run with highest privileges"

Comment: I'd be looking at the user on the errors in the event viewer and also the user on the scheduled task. Can you set the scheduled task user to yourself? Perhaps you changed password recently and haven't updated the password on the scheduled task?

Comment: I haven't changed the password but I think you were still correct -- It did have to do with the task scheduler running as a different user. It's a bit strange, it was set to run as "Administrator" but I changed it to "Administrators" and it seems to have worked. I'll have to wait and see tomorrow if it works the way it's supposed to. In the meantime, if you'd like to add that as an answer rather than just a comment I will most likely accept it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check

1. Which user is the scheduled task running as? Is it the same user as the one double clicking on the icon?
2. Have you changed your password recently? You might need to update the password on the scheduled task
3. Go to the windows event viewer, are there any errors in there?

Comment: #1 pointed me to the answer. It turns out that having the task sheduler run as user "Administrator" is different from running it as "Administrator**s**". I changed the user to "Administrators" and it worked as expected. Thanks!